# linq to XML: unique attribute value count per group

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have got XML nodes as below.

```
...
<ParentNode>
    <Node id="2343" name="some name" mode="Some Mode">
         //Some child nodes here
    </Node>
    <Node id="2344" name="some other name" mode="Some Mode">
         //Some child nodes here
    </Node>
    ...
</ParentNode>
<ParentNode>
    <Node id="2343" name="some name" mode="Some Other Mode">
         //Some child nodes here
    </Node>
    <Node id="2344" name="some other name" mode="Some Mode">
         //Some child nodes here
    </Node>
</ParentNode>
....
```

What I need is

```
id      name             distinct-mode-count
--------------------------------------------
2343    some name        2
2344    some other name  1
```

I have tried below to get this.

```
XElement myXML = XElement.Load(filePath);

IEnumerable<XElement> parentNodes = myXML.Descendants("ParentNode");

var nodeAttributes = parentNodes.Select(le => le.Descendants("Node")
    .GroupBy(x => new { 
                          id = x.Attribute("id").Value, 
                          name = x.Attribute("name").Value 
                      }).Select(g => new { 
                          id = g.Key.id, 
                          name = g.Key.name, 
                          distinct_mode_count = // This is where I am stuck
                      }));
```

I am not sure how to get `distinct_mode_count` in the above query.

**Edit**

I need distinct attribute value count for attribute `"mode"`, regardless of which `ParentNode` they are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the count of the distinct "mode" attribute values within the nodes with the same ID/name, you just need to project from each element in the group to the mode, then take the distinct sequence of those modes, then count it:

You just need to take the count of the group, and also use `SelectMany` to "flatten" your parent nodes. (Or just use `myXml.Descendants("Node")` to start with.)

Short but complete example which gives your desired results:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XElement myXML = XElement.Load("test.xml");

        IEnumerable<XElement> parentNodes = myXML.Descendants("ParentNode");
        var nodeAttributes = parentNodes
            .SelectMany(le => le.Descendants("Node"))
            .GroupBy(x => new { 
                Id = x.Attribute("id").Value, 
                Name = x.Attribute("name").Value 
            })
            .Select(g => new {
                g.Key.Id,
                g.Key.Name,
                DistinctModeCount = g.Select(x => x.Attribute("mode").Value)
                                     .Distinct()
                                     .Count()
            });
        foreach (var item in nodeAttributes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
XElement myXML = XElement.Load("test.xml");

var nodeAttributes = myXML
    .Descendants("Node")
    .GroupBy(...)
    // Remaining code as before
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @Jon Skeet. I need the distinct count within all parent nodes. Same node/parent node does not matter.

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi: It's not clear what you mean by that, nor is it clear in your question. Please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi: I've edited my answer slightly, and put it into a short but complete program, which gives your desired results.

Comment: This is working, thanks Jon! I need to do some more processing with the `parentNodes`. That is why I haven't taken `Node` as direct `Descendents`.